# Strange string(REGEX REPLACE) behaviour in CMake

Tags: c++, regex, sed, cmake

I have a string "`abc def ghi`" and I want to split it into "`abc`" and "`def ghi`" using CMake. In my script I have following two lines:

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "[ ].*" "" NAME ${VAR} )
string(REGEX REPLACE "^[^ ]*[ ]" "" OPTIONS ${VAR} )
```

First line works as expected, however the second one always outputs only the last supplied argument. I tried to replicate my problem using `sed` to check if there are any problems in my patterns and found the following results:

- `echo "abc def ghi" | sed "s/^[^ ]*[ ]//"` outputs "def ghi"
- `echo "abc def ghi" | sed "s/^[^ ]*[ ]//g"` outputs "ghi"

So it seem that my problem is that `string(REGEX REPLACE)` uses output of it's last operation as an input to the next one, like in second `sed` command. In documentation for `string` it says:

> REGEX REPLACE will match the regular expression as many times as possible and substitute the replacement expression for the match in the output.

but there is no mention of observed "piped output" behavior, which render `^` operator useless in my case. Is that a well known behavior for multiple-matching regex expressions? Is it possible to force `^` to match only actual beginning of first input, instead of beginning of each consecutive inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing second line with `string(REGEX MATCHALL "[ ](.*)" OPTIONS ${LIB} )` does what I want it to do (ignoring leading spaces but it's not a big deal). However it still doesn't answer the question about expected behavior in more general context outside this CMake function and more strict usage `^`.